# How to have "block all sites from example.com" always displayed on Google

Tags: google-search

Sometimes I see a link added to Google search results to "block all results from example.com" except this link is never displayed for the domains which I actually want to block. Is there some way to have this link displayed for every result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you are logged in to Google go to [this address](http://www.google.com/reviews/t?hl=en). It will let you block up to 500 sites from showing up in your search results.

Comment: You can also access the site-blocking feature by visiting your Google dashboard @ google.com/dashboard

Comment: This page doesn't exist anymore, and the dashboard does not contain a widget for Google Search.