# Is there a way to tell Google I don't want results from a certain website?

Tags: google-search

If you are logged into your Google account, search results are personalized for you based on what Google *thinks* you are more likely to be interested in.

Is there a way (other than creating a custom search widget) to tell Google *I'm not interested in any results from X site*?

Browser: Google Chrome 18.0.1025.162, on xubuntu

Comment: Closely related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19887/how-to-have-block-all-sites-from-x-com-always-displayed-on-google http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27510/activating-googles-block-results-from-this-site-when-you-need-it http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15951/how-to-search-for-product-reviews-without-junk-sites http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23551/blocking-all-about-com-websites-about-com-from-my-google-search-results

Comment: I think most of the answers described below are no longer supported, as of the date I commented. But this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-search-filter/eidhkmnbiahhgbgpjpiimdogfidfikgf?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) would do the work nicely.

Answer (score 9):

Add the following to your searches:

> -site:example.com

Comment: Yes, this does the trick, but you have to type the damn site's name in your search every time!

Answer (score 0):

An extension called [Google Search Filter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-search-filter/eidhkmnbiahhgbgpjpiimdogfidfikgf) in Google Chrome browser made it easy

[image: hide]